# htacces target specific file

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, caching, service-worker

This should be straight forward but apparently not.

I am trying to avoid a service-worker file from being cached on a Apache server.

The file is `sw.js` and its placed on `/public_html/`, as it should.

I have tried several combinations of the `<FilesMatch ??? >` below, like `"sw\.js$"` without success.

```
<FilesMatch "^(sw\.js)$">
  FileETag None
  <ifModule mod_headers.c>
    Header unset ETag
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
    Header set Pragma "no-cache"
    Header set Expires "Wed, 08 Jan 1975 05:00:00 GMT"
  </ifModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

According [to this](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/service-worker-checklist) ,if I run

```
 `curl -I -L https://www.soeezauto.com/sw.js | grep cache-control`
```

I should receive a `cache-control: no-cache`, but I do not.

Comment: Your `<FilesMatch>` directive should match, but since you are matching just a single file, you could simply use `<Files "sw.js">` - no need for regex here. Try setting a custom test header just in case these cache headers are being overridden... `Header set X-TEST "test"`.

Comment: This works fine on my Apache. Use `grep -iF 'cache-control'` to check

Comment: @DocRoot. I did try with <Files as well. Failed to mention that. But anubhava is right about the -iF flag.

Comment: @anubhava. It works indeed. Please post  elaborate on the why ( what does the -if flag doest ) and post it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex inside `FilesMatch` directive appears correct. However do note that Apache will send following header in response:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
```

Notice mixed case header name here `Cache-Control`.

Your `grep` command is searching for all lowercase header name i.e. `cache-control`, hence no output is showing.

You need to use `-i` (ignore case) matching in `grep` or search for exact same header i.e. `Cache-Control`.

So any of the following `grep` will work:

```
grep -i 'cache-control'
```

or

```
grep 'Cache-Control'
```

For better efficiency add `-F` option for fixed string search since you're not using any regex in `grep` pattern to make it:

```
grep -iF 'cache-control'
```